# Contingency table in SAS

Tags: sas

I have data on exam results for 2 years for a number of students. I have a column with the year, the students name and the mark. Some students don't appear in year 2 because they don't sit any exams in the second year. I want to show whether the performance of students persists or whether there's any pattern in their subsequent performance. I can split the data into two halves of equal size to account for the 'first-half' and 'second-half' marks. I can also split the first half into quintiles according to the exam results using 'proc rank'

I know the output I want is a 5 X 5 table that has the original 5 quintiles on one axis and the 5 subsequent quintiles plus a 'dropped out' category as well, so a 5 x 6 matrix. There will obviously be around 20% of the total number of students in each quintile in the first exam, and if there's no relationship there should be 16.67% in each of the 6 susequent categories. But I don't know how to proceed to show whether this is the case of not with this data.

How can I go about doing this in SAS, please? Could someone point me towards a good tutorial that would show how to set this up? I've been searching for terms like 'performance persistence' etc, but to no avail. . .

I've been proceeding like this to set up my dataset. I've added a column with 0 or 1 for the first or second half of the data using the first procedure below. I've also added a column with the quintile rank in terms of marks for all the students. But I think I've gone about this the wrong way. Shoudn't I be dividing the data into quintiles in each half, rather than across the whole two periods?

```
Proc rank groups=2;
      var yearquarter;
 ranks ExamRank;
run;

Proc rank groups=5;
      var percentageResult;
      ranks PerformanceRank;
run;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bases SAS: I'm not too sure. The command line version.

Comment: Both can be edited the same way.  SAS/IML is the matrix language (so, like R).  Base SAS has datasets but not matrices.

Comment: I understand. I'm in beginner with SAS, so would prefer using some of the PROC functions rather than doing it step-by-step in matrix algrebra with SAS/IML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fairly basic example of the simple tabulation.  I transpose your quintile data and then make a table.  Here there is basically no relationship, except that I only allow a 5% DNF so you have more like 19% 19% 19% 19% 19% 5%.

```
data have;
do i = 1 to 10000;
  do year = 1 to 2;
    if year=2 and ranuni(7) < 0.05 then call missing(quintile);
    else quintile = ceil(5*ranuni(7));
    output;
  end;
end;
run;

proc transpose data=have prefix=year out=have_t;
by i;
var quintile;
id year;
run;


proc tabulate data=have_t missing;
class year1 year2;
tables year1,year2*rowpctn;
run;
```

PROC CORRESP might be helpful for the analysis, though it doesn't look like it exactly does what you want.

```
proc corresp data=have_t outc=want outf=want2 missing;
tables year1,year2;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is this kind of analysis anyway? Is it a cross-tabulation, a contingency table or what is it exactly? I need to read much more about this to be able to extend the analysis.

Comment: My table is a cross-tabulation, but it's a cross-tabulation that is a contingency table.  As far as your analysis, I'm not really sure; you are certainly building a contingency table, but what you really want to analyze I'm not sure of.  You might ask either in the stats stackexchange, or ask on the SAS Listserv (sasl@listserv.uga.edu) to get more statistically focused advice.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you dividing the data into quintiles?

I would leave the scores as they are, then make a scatterplot with

```
PROC SGPLOT data = dataset;
 x = year1;
 y = year2;
 loess x = year1 y = year2;
run;
```